# put two uiimageView at the background

Tags: iphone, xcode, animation, background, uiimageview

here is my code:

```
-(void)transition{
CATransition *applicationLoadViewIn = [CATransition animation];
[applicationLoadViewIn setDuration:2];
[applicationLoadViewIn setType:kCATransitionFade];
[applicationLoadViewIn setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];
[[self.view layer] addAnimation:applicationLoadViewIn forKey:kCATransitionFade];
    imgView2 =   [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bluefont.png"]];          


if(self.view.layer.sublayers.count<=2)

{
    [[[self view] layer] addSublayer:[imgView2 layer]];
}
else {

    [[self.view.layer.sublayers lastObject] removeFromSuperlayer];
}

[imgView2 release];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
        imgView =   [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pinkfont.png"]];           
[[[self view] layer] addSublayer:[imgView layer]];
    [imgView release];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(transition) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

}

I want to send imgView2 and imgView to the background, thus the background is changing between the blue and pink colour.How can I do this please ? sorry for my english I'm french :/

Answer (score 0):

by using the frames you can add two imageviews to the background

Comment: image1.frame=cgrectmake(0,0,320,160);                                  image2.frame=cgrectmake(0,160,320,160);

Comment: no you don't understand "imgView2" takes all the screen and I want it to fade to another image which is "imgView"

Comment: I'm trying to set an image in the background and then change it to another image

Answer (score 0):

It may be useful

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
```

By changing the backgroundimage name you can achieve.